# Right click menu does not display in Firefox

Tags: firefox, context-menu, debian-jessie, right-click

I'm running Firefox 51.0 (64-bit) on Debian GNU/Linux 8.7 (jessie).

The right click menu does not display when I right-click the page.  This was happening before, stopped after I did an apt-get upgrade, and has no started again.

Instead of the normal right-click behavior, it alternates between two cursors, generally the text cursor and the pointer cursor.

This is reproducible on any site, including example.com

It happens even in safe mode, with a completely new profile.

There is nothing wrong with the hardware.  Right-click works fine in other programs.

Mozilla bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1344620

Debian bug: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=856911

Answer (score 0):

After [backing up your profiles](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/back-and-restore-information-firefox-profiles?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Backing%20up%20your%20information), try trashing Firefox and reinstalling.

If that doesn’t work, you could try using `apt-get purge` and reinstalling again (without the profile backups).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried apt-get purge (completely removing Debian-packaged Firefox), then a completely fresh profile (with upstream Firefox installed from tar.bz2), but that does not solve it.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. Unfortunately, I can't help you any further. :( Good luck solving it!